# How do I make it so the app will automatically call getlocationpermission after the user returns from enabling location permission automatically

Tags: java, android-studio, while-loop, geolocation, android-permissions

```
   public void statusCheck() {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }

    while(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && i<2)
    {
        getLocationPermission();
        i++;

    }
}
```

This is my code. Right now if location permission is not enabled, there will be an alert dialog that will take the user to their settings to enable it. However, when they return `getlocationpermission()` is not run so the app won't work. How do I make it so that the app will automatically call `getlocationpermission()` after the user returns from enabling location permission? Why is my code not working, why will it not call `getLocationpermission` after user `manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` is true.

Answer (score 0):

i think it need more time to connect GPS,
try use boolean.

Exemple:

```
while(!GpsWorking)
{
    getLocationPermission();
}

publick void  getLocationPermission()
{
//if gps working
GpsWorking = true;
}
```

in simple terms you will call the method until you get the location

once the location is received, the **while(!GpsWorking)** will exit